# Dynamically generated radiobutton is not aligned when screen resolution changes

Tags: jquery, css, radio-button

I have dynamically generated radiobutton. With the current specification its displaying nicely in my screen, but its not aligned in other users screen .How can i make it aligned.

```
$.each(result, function (key, value) {
    $("#PreferredTimeSlot").append(`<input type="radio" class="form-check-inline mr-2" value="${value.hourlyBasedTime}" name="ManageBooking.PreferredTimeslot" />${value.hourlyBasedTime} <span></span>`);
 });
```

[image]

I want the radiobuttons to be aligned like this

[image]

Comment: add css class or grid logic to align them? Rotation and css are not causing issue here. If we can have online example in fiddle or sandbox would help

Comment: Wrapping the input and the following text into a common parent, and then applying `white-space: pre` to that, should probably already be enough here - because your problem is not resulting from different widths to begin with, but only from the fact that line breaks are made within those texts. And that wrapping element should ideally be a `label` - so that the radio buttons can be checked by clicking on the text as well.

Comment: If your issue has been fixed with help from the comments, please consider either adding your own answer (with full details/solution) or closing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @CBroe for your solution.
Here are the changes done for fixing the alignment issues.

```
$("#PreferredTimeSlot").append(`<label style="white-space:pre"><input type="radio" class="form-check-inline mr-2" value="${value.hourlyBasedTime}" name="ManageBooking.PreferredTimeslot" />${value.hourlyBasedTime} <span></span></label>`);
```